# Jenkins issue while adding jira site using OAuth

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-jira-trigger

[error seen while trying to test connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bFx0.jpg)

I am getting an error "Invalid input length 849" when I  tried to test the connection with the Jira site in Jenkins. I tried to add the site in the Jenkins->configure system section using OAuth.But I can save it.

Comment: i used  this  guide  https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/jira-rest-api-oauth-authentication/ for creating the keys and configuring Jira and jenkins

Comment: I am using Jenkins 2.368 and jira cloud site

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-68495

Hope they will fix it a day or another...